# How to deal with Metadata which do not support deletion like LiveChatButton and Skill? I can't uninstall the unlocked package because of them

Tags: unlocked-package, unlocked, skill, livechatbutton

Looks like if some metadata components are ever included into unlocked package, it is completely impossible to uninstall such unlocked package or even remove these metadata from unlocked package.

Such metadata include: LiveChatButton and Skill.

[image]

Even though on UI they are not displayed, they are still kept as linked to this unlocked package preventing uninstall operation.

[image]

Which prevents from refactoring to move them into another package.

How this can be resolved?

I understand that for the other cases, like Digital Experience Bundle, even though they can't be deleted, they at least can be removed from the package and the unlocked package which used to contain a community can be finally removed by manually removing community link, but what can I do with `Skill` and `LiveChatButton`?

Switch parameter `--upgrade-type Delete` doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was a bad idea to include `Skill` and `LiveChatButton` into unlocked package.

These objects are not supported by  [Metadata Coverage report page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/60).

However, if you are using --skip-validation parameter, you may create package version which contains unsupported components such as those.

They should never be included into unlocked package since if they are ever included, they block uninstallation of the package which cannot be resolved.

I cannot even delete those from org using metadata API

[image]

because of these errors

```
delete() not supported for LiveChatButton
```

and

```
delete() not supported for Skill
```

Comment: Just FYI the [metadata coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/60) would tell you they're not supported for unlocked packaging as well.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves looks like it says they are not even supported, I am surprized then that I was able to include them into my package version